# Inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am reading this one JS book that talks about inheritance and I am really confused at what each line is doing. Can someone let me know if my understanding is correct or not.

```
function classA(sColor){
   this.color = sColor;
   this.sayColor = function (){
      alert(this.color);
   };
}

function ClassB(sColor, sName){
   this.newMethod = classA; //assigning a reference to a parent class
   this.newMethod(sColor);  //calling the constructor of the parent class

   //question: so what is 'this' then? from my understanding when we call 'new ClassB('a','b')'
   //we instantiate a new object and that new object becomes the 'this' in this case. Does this
   //line mean we are converting the this to classA?

   delete this.newMethod;   //deleting reference to the CONSTRUCTOR of the parent class

   this.name = sName;
   this.sayName = function(){
      alert(this.name);
   }

}
```

Comment: If this is the inheritance patterns your book is teaching you, I would go get another book. The Good Parts by Crockford, for instance.

Comment: I rarely actually use inheritance in js, but understanding `this` is important.  If you goal is to understand what is going on thats cool, but if you want to understand inheritance it is well kinda not used.  At least inheritance is used like you are doing it above.

Comment: this is the first inheritance example shown by the book and yes i am trying to understand what 'this' is at every place in the code.

Comment: which book? I agree with Magnar that the good parts (and the definitive guide) are the books you should read.

Comment: Professional JavaScript For WebDevelopers. I tried reading the definitive guide and boyyy it was sooo dryyyyyyyy. I have not tried reading tthe good parts though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How `this` works](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this)

```
function ClassB(sColor, sName){
   this.newMethod = classA; 
   this.newMethod(sColor);  

   delete this.newMethod;

   this.name = sName;
   this.sayName = function(){
      alert(this.name);
   }
}
```

Is a mediocre way of doing this

```
function ClassB(sColor, sName){
   classA.call(this, sColor); 

   this.name = sName;
   this.sayName = function(){
      alert(this.name);
   }
}

var f = new ClassB("green", "boy");
f.sayName(); // boy
f.sayColor(); // green
```

Your basically calling the `classA` constructor with your `this` object.

JavaScript does not have classes, it just has objects and functions that manipulate objects. Your `ClassA` function manipulates `this` and so does `ClassB`.

`ClassA` is just a function that manipulates an object. In this case it manipulates the `context` object which is `this`. All `ClassB` is doing is saying

- let ClassA manipulate `this`
- add a property called `name` to `this`
- add a method called `sayName` to `this`

**Bonus:**

There's a better way to do OO in JavaScript

```
// A is a blueprint for an object with a method sayColor
var A = (function() {
  var self = Object.create({});
  self.sayColor = function() { 
    alert(this.color);
  };
  return self;
}());

// B is a blueprint for an object with methods sayColor and sayName
var B = (function() {
  // clone the methods from A
  var self = Object.create(A);
  self.sayName = function() {
    alert(this.name);
  };
  return self;
}());

// clone B and set the properties for name and color
var b = Object.create(B, {
  name: { value: "boy" },
  color: { value: "green" }
});

/* or use a factory

var bFactory = function(name, color) {
  return Object.create(B, {
    name: { value: name },
    color: { value: boy }
  });
}

b = bFactory("boy", "green");

*/

b.sayName();
b.sayColor();
```

Use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) which is ES5 so use the [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) to support legacy browsers.

Comment: who keeps reference to the newly instantiated classA instance?

Comment: @denniss you don't create a new instance of classA unless you call `new classA`. What your actually doing is calling the `ClassA` function and saying use the `this` in `ClassB` as the `this` in `ClassA`